# Find object's class

Tags: java, sonarqube, rule

Currently I have task to migrate some rules in SonarQube. Older ones are based on PMD and Checkstyle libraries. New ones need to be written with integrated Sonar rules (like most squid rules). Rule I'm currently working on needs to check if any method from class which contains "Dao" in it's name is used in loop.

I'm not quite experienced with rules migration and use of sonar libraries, so I am trying to use some parts from squid rules but I'm not able to find exactly what i need.

```
@Override
public void visitNode(Tree tree) {
   MethodInvocationTree methodInvocationTree = (MethodInvocationTree) tree;
   IdentifierTree methodName = methodName(methodInvocationTree);

   if ( methodClassContainsDaoInName(tree?) && insideLoop(tree?)) {
      reportIssue(methodName, "DAO methods should not be called inside loop");
   }
}
```

I'm still stuck on first method (methodClassContainsDaoInName()). Currently I'm trying to get method and object and check if that object's class has "Dao" in it's name. I use this command:

```
tree.parent().firstToken().text();
```

this command finds my object but only gives me it's name. I tried to do this:

```
tree.parent().firstToken().toClass();
```

but it gives me wrong class (If I recall correctly it returns symbol or token class).

Maybe someone know how could I convert that result to correct object? 
Maybe someone know better way to make this rule alive and could share some examples?

Comment: I think you want something like Object.getClass().getName()

Comment: @MichaelPeacock nop, really not. all the info is within the syntax Tree API.

Comment: Yes I want to get object's class but this rule needs to be universal so I don't have object before checking project. This method would fit me but first i need to find that object (or multiple objects)

Comment: Have you tried `methodInvocation.symbol().owner().name()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a disclaimer, I'm not going to write the rule for you. Everything should be available from the API (syntax or semantic)... Once correctly formulated your requirement in term of rule writing and concepts.

To reformulate the requirement: You are trying to verify that the class (the object...) *owning* the called method is a DAO (a.k.a. the *owner*), and if it's the case, raise an issue (if it's within a loop, but that's another story).

Now, from the `methodInvocationTree` itself that you already have, access its associated `symbol` (there is a `symbol()` method in the API), then it's `owner` symbol, which *should* be the owning class. From the owner symbol, you can then access directly its `name`, and validate if it contains "Dao".

Put into code:

```
boolean methodFromDao = methodInvocationTree
  .symbol()
  .owner()
  .name()
  .contains("Dao");
```

**Important note:** From the syntax API, you used another level of abstraction from the SonarJava API, which gives you access to symbols. In order to complete the semantic, SonarJava requires access to bytecode during analysis. If bytecode is not provided, it is most likely that methods won't be resolved by the semantic engine. Concretely, it means that all the symbols will be `unknown`, and you won't be able to know their owners.

Comment: I tried some methods with symbol last week but unsuccessfully. I was getting name: "Object". 
I tried this code and it was returning same values. It looks like main problem was in my testing project: I tried to call testDao.toString() which returned internDao as Object while i wanted to get TestDao. 
When i tried to call another method which I wrote myself in TestDao class, it returned "TestDao" class and "true". 
Thank you

Comment: Which is logical... if you were calling methods inherited from `java.lang.Object` and not overridden. If you override the `toString()` method, you should then get your `TestDao` class when looking for the owner.